# How to list by letter only?

Tags: c++

I have 2 functions below. How do I change the code so that it will display by letter?

e.g if I define "A", it will only showAllRecords that begin with A.

```
char* displayRecordContent (CountryRecordType ctryRec)
{
  char * output;
  output = ctryRec.Country;
  return output;
}

// ====================================================================

void showAllRecords ()
{
  int i=0;
  char * result;
  for (i=0; i<NoOfRecordsRead; i++)
  {
    result = displayRecordContent (globalCountryDataArray [i]);
    printf ("(%d) %s\n", i, result);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
(0) Andorra
(1) United Arab Emirates
(2) Afghanistan
(3) Antigua and Barbuda
(4) Anguilla
(5) Albania
(6) Armenia
(7) Netherlands Antilles
(8) Angola
(9) Antarctica
```

Comment: When asking 'how do I do this?' questions it's helpful if you show what you've tried so far. This is because a) it's easier to tell what is being asked, b) it's easier to tell what you might be stuck on, c) it's a good indication of your ability so answers can be framed appropriately, d) it gives people confidence that you are actually trying to learn and not just asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: This bears only the most superficial resemblance to C++. If I were you, I'd start by finding a source to learn C++ that teaches actual C++, instead of C that you compiled with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void showAllRecords (char begin)
{
  int i=0, j=0;
  char * result;
  for (i=0; i<NoOfRecordsRead; i++)
  {
    result = displayRecordContent (globalCountryDataArray [i]);
    if (result[0] == begin) {
        printf ("(%d) %s\n", j, result);
        j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
void showAllRecords ()
{
  int i=0;
  char * result;
  for (i=0; i<NoOfRecordsRead; i++)
  {
    result = displayRecordContent (globalCountryDataArray [i]);
    if(*result == 'A') // or other letter
      printf ("(%d) %s\n", i, result);
  }
}
```